# Algolia / Laravel / Attributes for Faceting

Tags: laravel, algolia

Doing a lot of testing and playing so added a small bit of code that I can use the

```
::reindex()
```

on my model to resync everything. All good and I can use

```
public $indices = ['title', 'filename', 'description'];
```

Which creates my searchable attributes, but I can't see how to define the Attributes for faceting :( sure it's something really obvious? HELP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify those settings in [`$algoliaSettings`](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel#ranking--relevance) variable inside you model.

```
public $algoliaSettings = [
    'attributesForFaceting' => [
        'attributeName',
        'otherAttributeName',
    ],
];
```

And then those settings will be set to your index on calling `YourModel::setSettings();` or `YourModel::reindex();`

Comment: Hmm, thanks... So by setting that it doesn't delete the current facets, but if they don't exist they don't get recreated either. So it's a kind of fix but not what I was expecting at the same time?